# Dynamically create instance(s) of C# class

Tags: c#, .net

I want to dynamically create instances of a class, so I created a dictionary of objects of that class and assign the names by appending a counter to a string. But how do I access the properties of the objects?

The code is something like this:

```
int count = 0;
string name = "MyInstanceName" + count.ToString();

Dictionary<string, MyClass> d = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
d.Add(name, new MyClass(Parameter));

//try to retrieve the Property - this doesn't work
textBox1.Text = d[name.Property];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this

```
int count = 0;
string name = "MyInstanceName" + count.ToString();

var d = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
d.Add(name, new MyClass());

textBox1.Text = d[name].Property;
```

You created a `Dictionary` that the key is a `string` and the value is a instance of `MyClass`.

When using Dictionary index, the value between brackets `[]` should be the key, in this case a string.

```
myDictionary["keyValue"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox1.Text = d[name].Property;
```

Comment: You know the drill :-) ... add a bit of explanation so we don't have to agonize about whether it's "low quality" :-)?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Alberto Monteiro's answer, don't forget to cast your object:

```
textBox1.Text = (myClass) d["MyInstanceName1"].Property;
```

or

```
var myInstanceX = d["MyInstanceName1"].Property;
textBox1.Text = myInstanceX.myStringProperty();
```

In C# (unlike VB), you don't need to specify the type of a variable if the compiler can determine it elsewhere, so you can also simplify:

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> d = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
```

into

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
```

var is a typed variable declarator (unlike javascript)

Comment: There is no need to cast